# Will Flink finish the sink process when sent a stop command

Tags: apache-flink

Here is my question : 
Will filnk finish the sink process and rename the .inprogress files to part-x-x files when sending a stop command?

I find my flink tasks(using flink-1.9.1) will not rename the .inprogress files to part-x-x files. But I read the source code, it says

`org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient#stopWithSavepoint`:

```
 * Stops a program on Flink cluster whose job-manager is configured in this client's configuration.
 * Stopping works only for streaming programs. Be aware, that the program might continue to run for
 * a while after sending the stop command, because after sources stopped to emit data all operators
 * need to finish processing.
```

Comment: Which sink function are you referring to?

Comment: it's StreamingFileSink

Answer (score 0):

The StreamingFileSink does have some limitations in this regard. See [this thread](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/StreamingFileSink-Not-Flushing-All-Data-tc33009.html#none) from the user@flink.apache.org mailing list.

[FLIP-46](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-46%3A+Graceful+Shutdown+Handling+by+UDFs), which is being tracked as [FLINK-13103](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-13103), is needed in order to fix this. Until then, the StreamingFileSink will remain unable to transition unfinished files to the finished state when a job is stopped. This is described in the documentation as [Important Note 2](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/streamfile_sink.html#important-considerations).